# Put Where Clause in a parameter

Tags: sql, t-sql

I would like to use a where clause in a parameter. I already tried the following code but it doesnt work. the last line us red underlined, i reckon that i have to bind the parameter to the select command somehow. Would be great if anyone could help me with it.

```
Begin
declare @name varchar(MAX)
declare @x int
Set @x = 1
If @x = 1
BEGIN
SET @name = 'WHERE Username = Frank'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SET @name = ''
END
END
```

now use it in:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.person @name
```

Comment: you will have to do this with some dynamic sql.

Comment: Is the Where clause truly dynamic or are you offering the choice of a user name or all records?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a typical way to have optional parameters in a query:

```
declare @UserName varchar(255) = 'Frank'

select *
from person p
where (@UserName is null or UserName = @UserName)
```

If you set the variable to `NULL` then all users are chosen.  If you set it to a value, then only that user is chosen.

Comment: That is exactley what i was looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: @ruedi . . . Glad I could be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want an optional Stored Procedure parameter to either pull rows with the parameter value or pull all rows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE foo
    @name AS VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL
AS
BEGIN

SELECT * FROM dbo.person WHERE Username = @name OR @name IS NULL

END
GO
```